# Insulating container in real life

Tags: thermodynamics

Is it possible to practically build a perfectly insulating container? If not, what's the best way to build one? By perfectly I mean no heat is trasferred over an infinite amount of time.

Comment: As you are speaking in the realm of the imagination with assumptions which are not realistic, to try to build a practical example, then practical example is a self-contained/isolated universe. No energy out or in, just the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Harish Chandra Rajpoot removed his answer instead of rectifying to:

"No, it is not possible to practically build a perfectly insulating container, but even in commercial products we try to get as close as we can get, for example, a "thermos""

The problem is that no material exists that reflects 100% of all electromagnetic radiation, and so, you cannot contain radiation energy dissipation from a closed system within our universe. In other words, every material radiates energy (black body radiation), and it is not possible to contain all this radiation inside one single container. But then we can try our best and use materials that reflect as much as possible back into the thing we want to isolate.

Addressing now the other forms of energy dissipation: convection and conduction. Convection, for liquids and gases, is easy to handle, just build a vacuum around the thing you want to isolate. But then you have conduction. Either you suspend your thing in vacuum, using for example some form of electro-magnetic levitation or you have the container passively supported via physical solid contacts. In the first case, you are wasting energy just to be sure your container stays in no contact with your outer vacuum walls, in the second, contact means there is conduction of heat between your container and the outward vacuum walls, also dissipating heat.

So, in short, we cannot. But the closest we can get, we try, i.e. in refrigerators or thermal-bottles.

Answer (score 2):

It's not practically possible to build a perfectly insulating container as there is no perfect insulating material. But a closed container can be very close to a perfectly insulating container.

Vacuum offers the highest thermal resistance to the conduction and convection heat transfers. Therefore vacuum is the best insulator for preventing conduction and convection heat transfers.

Similarly, a highly polished or shiny surface like silver or aluminium foils\shields can be used to prevent the radiation heat transfer. If we use a large number of thin radiation shields, the heat transfer becomes almost negligible.

If we place a large number of thin (foil) radiation shields keeping a vacuum gap between each two shields in form of spherical shells, a spherical closed container (a cork less) can be practically made  such that the heat transfer through it becomes almost negligible ideally zero over very long period of time.

[image]

Comment: To be perfectly clear, a perfect vacuum is a perfect insulator for conduction and convection.

Comment: You are right but perfect vacuum again practically not possible. I said vacuum not perfect vacuum similar to as insulator and a perfect insulator.

Comment: I think the force of your answer could be improved by making this statement directly in the answer rather than in a comment.

Comment: Yes, I have clearly mentioned in my answer that vacuum is best insulator which practically possible. On the other side,a perfect vacuum is perfect insulator but not practically possible

Comment: Better, but I still think you underplay the fact that 1- silver/aluminium/whatever material you can think of, will absorb a non-negligible part of radiation. This scatters the BBR around your shells. Yes, almost no radiation is coming out, but it still is dissipated from the main vessel to the shells as BBR is a random process. I do not know how long it would take for a 1kg of water at 80°C in the main vessel to go down to say 75°C, but I can imagine this would happen in less than a human lifetime...which is nothing in terms of cosmic times.